# Geoserver-WMS-problem when zooming point layer

Tags: geoserver, wms, point

I need help. I would like to have no blank(white) space between points when zooming in WMS geoserver.
[image: This is OK, whitout blank space between points at the smallest zoom]

[image: When I zoom in, blank spaces appear, but I don't want that]

Any idea?

Comment: you have to fix zoom level : maxScale and minScale on the layers instead of resolution

Comment: I tried with <MinScaleDenominator> and </MaxScaleDenominator> but didn't work. First picture is OK at the smallest zoom, but when I zoom in, blank spaces appear on picture 2.

Comment: I think you need to convert your points to a raster layer which is a different question